# ¿Cómo combinar dos comandos sed?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, sed

Necesito combinar este comando sed:

```
sed 's/T[[:digit:]].*//' song.json
```

con este otro comando sed:

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{2,4})([[:digit:]]{1,2})([[:digit:]]{1,2})/\3\-\2\-\1/g'
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es transformar este formato de fecha:

```
20200426T200000
```

en este otro:

```
26-04-2020
```

¿Cómo puedo combinar los dos comandos sed?

Comment: Sergei, si quieres comentar, hazlo en la zona de comentarios. Dices en https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/207974 que te está modificando otras partes del archivo. Para evitarlo, iría bien que indicaras cómo es tu fichero, para así buscar patrones que permitan solamente modificar esta linea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinar se me ocurre de esta manera:

```
echo '20200426T200000' | sed -e 's/T[[:digit:]].*//' -re 's/([[:digit:]]{2,4})([[:digit:]]{1,2})([[:digit:]]{1,2})/\3\-\2\-\1/g'
```

Lo que sucede aquí es muy sencillo y es que `sed` tiene los parametros:

- `-e` Indica que añade un script (tu comando `s/etc//`),
- `-r` Habilita las expresiones regulares,

por lo que `sed -e '<script>' -re '<script con regex no "triviales">'`, entonces con `-e` puedes combinar

**Nota**: Eso esta muy "feo". Si alguien (incluyendote a ti) lo quisiera editar en un futuro, no le sería tan fluido como podría ser.

Mi propuesta, que incluye al propio `sed`, es esta:

```
echo '20200426T200000' | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}).*/\3-\2-\1/'
```

La cual usa una expresión regular donde únicamente capturo en un grupo primero cuatro dígitos, luego dos, luego dos; esto para luego atrapar lo que siga (que no me interesa) y lo reacomodo como querías.

Sería útil que vieras si todas las fechas recibidas van a seguir ese formato (YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS) para que no haya problemas con el formato. Es muy frecuente encontrar problemas con el formato de fechas.

Otra opción que te ofrezco es el uso de `awk`:

```
echo '20200426T200000' | awk '{printf "%s-%s-%s", substr($0,7,2), substr($0,5,2), substr($0,1,4)}'
```

en donde hago uso de la función `substr` para indicar el índice de dónde quiero que busque sobre el registro y la cantidad de caracteres que debe de tomar a partir de ahí.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @sergei Si mi respuesta te funcionó, no olvides seleccionarla como la correcta para que otros usuarios que tengan preguntas semejantes puedan encontrarla facilmente.

Comment: Creo que la he seleccionado como correcta. ¿Es así?

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente pon un punto y coma:

```
sed 'comando1; comando2'
```

Ejemplo donde sustituyo 2 por X y 3 por Y:

```
$ echo "2324" | sed 's/2/X/' | sed 's/3/Y/'
XY24
$ echo "2324" | sed 's/2/X/;s/3/Y/'
XY24
```

En tu caso:

```
sed -r 's/T[[:digit:]].*//;s/([[:digit:]]{2,4})([[:digit:]]{1,2})([[:digit:]]{1,2})/\3\-\2\-\1/g'
```

---

Dicho lo cual, en tu caso particular puedes utilizar directamente `date` para que te escriba la fecha de una forma diferente.

- Tienes `20200426T200000` y solamente te interesa la parte a la izquierda de la "T".
- Una vez tienes eso, `date -d"<esa fecha>" "<un formato>"` te soluciona el problema.

Todo junto:

```
date -d"$(cut -d'T' -f1 <<< "<fecha>")" "+%d-%m-%Y"
```

Con tu valor:

```
$ f="20200426T200000"
$ date -d"$(cut -d'T' -f1 <<< "$f")" "+%d-%m-%Y"
26-04-2020
```

Comment: He probado a hacer lo que me indicas, pero me cambia el formato en otras partes del archivo que no se tienen que modificar. Por ejemplo, en las líneas que aparece esto: "address": "Riera, 5-7 08038 Barcelona", lo transforma en este otro formato: "address": "Riera, 5-7 8-3-080 Barcelona",

Comment: Tengo que utilizar forzosamente sed.

Comment: iría bien que indicaras cómo es tu fichero, para así buscar patrones que permitan solamente modificar esta linea

Comment: Poniendo solamente este comando, ya me cambia el formato donde tiene que hacerlo, sin cambiar lo demás: sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}).*/\3-\2-\1/' songs.json