# Error en regex con sed

Tags: regex, sed

Tengo esta regex:

```
sed "{
s/\(.*,\)\(yes\)\(.*\)/\1true\3/
s/\(.*,\)\(no\)\(.*\)/\1false\3/
/\(.*,\)[^yes-no],.*/d
}" student-mat.csv
```

Pero cuando la ejecuto me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 89: Final de rango inválido
```

He modificado esta parte: `[^yes-no],` por esta otra: `[^yes|no],` ya que parece ser que no me detectaba el rango correctamente. De esta forma desaparece el error pero no hace bien el cambio.

La idea es que modifique todos los `yes` por `true` y todos los `no` por `false`.

La estructura del `.csv` es la siguiente:

```
school  sex age address famsize Pstatus Medu    Fedu    Mjob    Fjob    reason  guardian    traveltime  studytime   failures    schoolsup   famsup  paid    activities  nursery higher  internet    romantic    famrel  freetime    goout   Dalc    Walc    health  absences    G1  G2  G3
GP  F   18  U   GT3 A   4   4   at_home teacher course  mother  2   2   0   yes no  no  no  yes yes no  no  4   3   4   1   1   3   6   5   6   6
GP  F   17  U   GT3 T   1   1   at_home other   course  father  1   2   0   no  yes no  no  no  yes yes no  5   3   3   1   1   3   4   5   5   6
GP  F   15  U   LE3 T   1   1   at_home other   other   mother  1   2   3   yes no  yes no  yes yes yes no  4   3   2   2   3   3   10  7   8   10
GP  F   15  U   GT3 T   4   2   health  services    home    mother  1   3   0   no  yes yes yes yes yes yes yes 3   2   2   1   1   5   2   15  14  15
GP  F   16  U   GT3 T   3   3   other   other   home    father  1   2   0   no  yes yes no  yes yes no  no  4   3   2   1   2   5   4   6   10  10
GP  M   16  U   LE3 T   4   3   services    other   reputation  mother  1   2   0   no  yes yes yes yes yes yes no  5   4   2   1   2   5   10  15  15  15
```

Al ejecutar el comando, solo modifica los 2 últimos valores que encuentra, pero ningún otro mas. **¿Como puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo combinar dos comandos sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346896/c%c3%b3mo-combinar-dos-comandos-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Respuesta editada:**

---

***Gracias al aporte de @Cuauhtli*** considero que esta solución es mejor a mi respuesta inicial (mediante pipes que consumian más tiempo por abrir el programa `sed` y procesar el texto varias veces en lugar de solo una):

```
sed 's/yes/true/g;s/no/false/g' student-mat.csv
```

**Respuesta inicial:**

---

¿Y encadenando comandos `sed` con pipes no te sirve?

Algo así como:

```
cat student-mat.csv | sed "s/yes/true/g" | sed "s/no/false/g" > student-mat-fixed.csv
```

Eso te crearia el archivo `student-mat-fixed.csv` con los cambios que pides.

Comment: O juntando todo: `sed 's/yes/true/g;s/no/false/g' student-mat.csv > student-mat-fixed.csv`.

Comment: @Cuauhtli: Vaya, no conocia esa sintaxis del `sed`, gracias (la de veces que pipeo cosas asi y no me habia preocupado de aprenderme mejor el comand `sed`)

Comment: Si pipeas todo eso, es más lento. Porque lo que haces es volver a abrir el programa sed y volver a procesar texto. Si lo haces todo junto, sólo abres el programa una vez.

Comment: @Cuauhtli: Entendido. He agregado tu aporte a mi respuesta. Gracias.